# How to hide accounts in explorer?

Tags: solana

For now solana explorer displays all the accounts pubkeys that interact in the instructions. Is there an option to hide these accounts in the instructions?

Answer (score 1):

The normal Solana explorer does not have this feature.  As an alternative, Solscan displays things slightly differently, but still shows all accounts, e.g. https://solscan.io/tx/2EKMjrv9bZgM6VjkNAyVeDkDYTyF1mV9Tj7czKtGF8UXmqg3Uwu4zbxmuQz6ArbVn1YsBZSvbMMMHE3qohw75P1j

If this is a feature that you would like to have added, feel free to add a feature request as an issue in the main repo: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues